# Generating an equivalent barplot using ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I have this data:

```
df <- structure(list(Study = 1:5, contributions = c(10L, 15L, 20L, 
50L, 5L)), .Names = c("Study", "contributions"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```

I want to generate a barplot. I am able to do that using this code:

```
par(mar = c(5, 10, 5, 5))
barplot(df$contributions, names = df$Study,
        xlim = c(0, 60), las = 2, horiz = T,
        col = "royalblue")
```

I need help in reproducing the plot generated by the above code but using using `ggplot2` library. This would make it easier for me to save and select proper resolution for the plot.

I reviewed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10352894/barplot-using-ggplot2) and tried:

```
library(ggplot2)
plotobj <- NULL 
plotobj <- ggplot(df,aes(x=contributions,y=Study)) 
plotobj <- plotobj + geom_bar(stat="identity",fill="royalblue") 
plotobj
```

But it didn't work.

Comment: @Pascal `plotobj <- NULL
plotobj <-  ggplot(df,aes(x=contributions,y=Study))
plotobj <-  plotobj + geom_bar(stat="identity",fill="royalblue")
plotobj`

Comment: Does `ggplot(df, aes(x=Study, y=contributions)) + geom_bar(stat="identity", fill="royalblue") + coord_flip()` do what you want?

Comment: Yes it does. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `coord_flip` function:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(x=Study, y=contributions)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity", fill="royalblue") + 
  coord_flip()
```

[image]