# Changing colours of grouped bar chart in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

For a sample dataframe:

```
df <- structure(list(year = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 
3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4), imd.quintile = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 
4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5), average_antibiotic = c(1.17153515458827, 
1.11592565388857, 1.09288449967773, 1.07442652168281, 1.06102887394413, 
1.0560582933182, 1.00678980505929, 0.992997489072538, 0.978343676071694, 
0.967900478870214, 1.02854157116164, 0.98339099101476, 0.981198852494798, 
0.971392872980818, 0.962289579742817, 1.00601488964457, 0.951187417739673, 
0.950706064156994, 0.939174499710836, 0.934948233015044)), .Names = c("year", 
"imd.quintile", "average_antibiotic"), row.names = c(NA, -20L
), vars = "year", drop = TRUE, class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I am producing a graph detailing the differences in antibiotic prescribing BY imd.decile BY year:

```
ggplot(plot_data.quintiles) + 
  geom_col(aes(x = year, y = average_antibiotic, group=imd.quintile, fill=imd.quintile), position = "dodge") +
             ylab("Antibiotic STAR-PU") +
  xlab("Year") +
  theme_bw() +
  ylim(0, 1.5)+
  scale_colour_brewer("clarity")
```

The blue colour choice isn't to my taste, as the differences between the imd.quintiles isn't very distinctive. I have read various posts, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15087902/r-bar-chart-colours-for-groups-of-bars), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15071334/boxplot-of-table-using-ggplot2/15071393#15071393) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10352894/barplot-using-ggplot2), but none of which seem to answer my question.

I attempted to use the 'clarity' colours to get a wider range of colour choices.  How can I correctly change the fill colour in my ggplot2 graph? what options do I have?

Answer (score 4):

Is this what you want? Use `factor(imd.quintile)` to create discrete (categorical) data otherwise `ggplot` will treat numeric/integer `imd.quintile` as continuous.

```r
df <- data.frame(
                 year = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4,
                          4, 4),
         imd.quintile = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3,
                          4, 5),
   average_antibiotic = c(1.17153515458827, 1.11592565388857, 1.09288449967773,
                          1.07442652168281, 1.06102887394413, 1.0560582933182,
                          1.00678980505929, 0.992997489072538, 0.978343676071694,
                          0.967900478870214, 1.02854157116164, 0.98339099101476,
                          0.981198852494798, 0.971392872980818,
                          0.962289579742817, 1.00601488964457, 0.951187417739673,
                          0.950706064156994, 0.939174499710836, 0.934948233015044)
)

library(ggplot2)
p1 <- ggplot(df) +
  geom_col(aes(
    x = year, y = average_antibiotic,
    group = imd.quintile, fill = factor(imd.quintile)), position = "dodge") +
  ylab("Antibiotic STAR-PU") +
  xlab("Year") +
  theme_bw() +
  ylim(0, 1.5)

p1 +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Set2") # use scale_fill_xxx to chose the desired color palette
```

[image]

If you prefer continuous (sequential) colormaps, [viridis](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/viridis/vignettes/intro-to-viridis.html) or [scico](https://github.com/thomasp85/scico) are good options:

```r
p1 +
  scale_fill_viridis_c(option = 'E', direction = -1)
```

[image]

```r
# install.packages('scico')
library(scico)
p1 +
  scale_fill_scico()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2018-11-29 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1.9000)</sup>

Answer (score 3):

`scale_####_brewer` uses palettes from `RColorBrewer`, there's no palette called "Clarity".

Use `RColorBrewer::display.brewer.all()` to see what palette's are available, then call them by name with the `palette` arg. Also you need to change the `imd.quintile` variable to be either character or factor. You're mapping your aesthetics by fill also, not colour, so you need to use `scale_fill_brewer`.

```
ggplot(df) + 
  geom_col(aes(x = year, y = average_antibiotic, group=imd.quintile, fill=imd.quintile), position = "dodge") +
  ylab("Antibiotic STAR-PU") +
  xlab("Year") +
  theme_bw() +
  ylim(0, 1.5) + 
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Spectral")
```