# mapping (ordered) factors to colors in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

Consider this example

```
data_frame(mylabel = c('month 18',
                       'month 19',
                       'month 20',
                       'month 21',
                       'month 22'),
           value = c(5,10,-2,2,0),
           time = c(1,2,3,4,5)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes( x= time, y = value, color = mylabel)) +
  geom_point(size = 7)
```

[image]

Here you can see that the variable `mylabel` has a natural ordering: month 18 comes before month 19 etc.

However, this natural ordering is not preserved by the colors chosen by `ggplot`. In my real dataset, I have about 50 different months and I would like to use a color scale that makes this increase more intuitive (say from cold to hot).

How can I do that?
Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide the expected output?

Comment: anything that preserves the ordering. Say some color scale that is colder for month 18 and 19 and hotter for month 21 and 22. You see what I mean?

Comment: Parse the number out of `mylabel` and then use it as a continuous variable and fix the legend as necessary? Or do you specifically want discrete colours rather than a gradient?

Comment: In your example the ordering is preserved but the factors will order lexicographically so you will have to fix that, if for example you have `factor(paste('month', 1:12))` the order will be 1, 10, 11, 12, 2, etc. But just for your example, all you have to do is add a `scale_color_manual()` with whatever colors you want. See https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/scale_manual.html

Comment: @qdread thank you nailed the problem exactly. how can I avoid re-ordering the factors manually?

Comment: @ℕʘʘḆḽḘ: something like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/53543662/786542?

Comment: I would create a separate variable that encodes the months' temparature, and then map on that, rather than the month#, which doesn't really encode the value

Comment: You can extract the numbers from the character vector with something like `as.numeric(gsub('month ', '', as.character(month)))` then use color scale based on the numbers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use the viridis color scale or another one which is better colored to indicate the order.

There are several options included for similar color scales (option = "A" through "D"). Change the order by `direction = -1`

I've added a step to get better ordering, in case months are listed incorrectly. It works, but I'm sure there's a simpler way. Pull out the month# from the name (has to be converted from `char` to `numeric`) and then factor it which will use the proper order.

```
library(tidyverse)
data_frame(mylabel = paste("month", 1:10),
             value = rnorm(length(mylabel)),
             time = seq_along(mylabel)) %>% 
    mutate(month_number = factor(as.numeric(gsub("month ([0-9]+)", "\\1", mylabel)))) %>% 
  ggplot(aes( x= time, y = value, color = month_number)) +
  geom_point(size = 7) +
  scale_color_viridis_d(option = "B", direction = -1)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2018-11-30 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Comment: thanks matt. but how can I solve the issue mentioned above that is with factor(paste('month', 1:12)) the order will be 1, 10, 11, 12, 2

Comment: I see, but I'm not sure which months are hot/cold by your list. I'll try to make something that could be adapted.

Comment: it does not really matter as long as ealier months are colored differentry than later month. Its a visual thing, really. thanks!

Comment: I think Matt L. did not understand that the mixed up ordering was an issue because your example only contains 18-22 which stays in the same order whether it is sorted by increasing number or lexicographically

Comment: i finally understood- that's a little bit of a separate question, but I've updated to get around that I think.

Answer (score 2):

The `as_factor` function in `forcats` orders levels as they occur, rather than first putting all that start with "1", then all that start with "2", etc. This dodges the problem with having months 1 through 12.

I made up different data just to get the full set of month labels.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(1234)
df <- data_frame(mylabel = paste("month", 1:12),
                 value = rnorm(12),
                 time = 1:12)

df_fact <- df %>%
  mutate(mylabel = forcats::as_factor(mylabel))

levels(df_fact$mylabel)
#>  [1] "month 1"  "month 2"  "month 3"  "month 4"  "month 5"  "month 6" 
#>  [7] "month 7"  "month 8"  "month 9"  "month 10" "month 11" "month 12"

ggplot(df_fact, aes(x = time, y = value, color = mylabel)) +
  geom_point(size = 7)
```

[image]

You can further adjust the color scale for one that better suits sequential data. I often use Color Brewer ones, but also like some of the `rcartocolor` scales. In this case, having 12 levels will max out the number of colors available in a lot of sequential palettes, although the Viridis scales that ship with `ggplot2` (e.g. `scale_color_viridis_d`) will interpolate to fit this many levels.

<sup>Created on 2018-11-30 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Comment: nice one but you kind of cheat :) your factor is already ordered in the right way! hehe

Comment: Within the original question, yours was as well, right? Ordering 2 before 12, etc. didn't come up as a concern until the comments