# fill value not mapping to correct factor ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to plot a scatter plot that is colored by variable, with the values on the x-axis filled using geom_rect. However i cannot work out how to make the factors map in the correct order.

Here is a sample of my data:

```
head(prod_cons_diff, n = 10)
# A tibble: 10 x 10
   country             year cons.e iso3c terr.e diff.prod.cons.e prod.cons                 continent xstart  xend
   <chr>              <int>  <dbl> <chr>  <dbl>            <dbl> <chr>                     <chr>      <dbl> <dbl>
 1 China               2017  2333. CHN    2685.           352.   Territorial > Consumption Asia         0.5   1.5
 2 USA                 2017  1552. USA    1439.          -113.   Consumption > Territorial Americas     1.5   2.5
 3 India               2017   617. IND     671.            53.8  Territorial > Consumption Asia         2.5   3.5
 4 Japan               2017   380. JPN     324.           -55.9  Consumption > Territorial Asia         3.5   4.5
 5 Russian Federation  2017   375. RUS     450.            74.9  Territorial > Consumption Europe       4.5   5.5
 6 Germany             2017   244. DEU     218.           -26.4  Consumption > Territorial Europe       5.5   6.5
 7 South Korea         2017   183. KOR     175.            -7.79 Consumption > Territorial Asia         6.5   7.5
 8 Saudi Arabia        2017   169. SAU     173.             3.62 Territorial > Consumption Asia         7.5   8.5
 9 Iran                2017   166. IRN     187.            20.8  Territorial > Consumption Asia         8.5   9.5
10 Indonesia           2017   164. IDN     159.            -4.62 Consumption > Territorial Asia         9.5  10.5
```

When I run the following ggplot script:

```
ggplot(prod_cons_diff, aes(x = fct_reorder(country, diff.prod.cons.e), y = diff.prod.cons.e * 3.664)) + 
  geom_point(aes(col = prod.cons)) + # add geom_point otherwise i can't map geom_rect (continuous) to country (discrete)
  geom_rect(aes(ymin = -1500, ymax = 1500, 
                xmin = xstart, xmax = xend, 
                fill = continent), alpha = 0.3, col = NA) + 
  geom_point(aes(col = prod.cons)) + # re-add geom_point so that it appears on top of the fill
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0, linetype = 'dashed') +
  coord_flip() +
  scale_color_manual(values = c('red', 'blue')) + 
  theme_minimal()
```

[image]

The fill variable however is clearly wrong: China is not in Europe, USA is not in Asia etc.

I tried setting country and continent as factors with specific levels, but couldn't get it right. I also tried answer 2 from here ([mapping (ordered) factors to colors in ggplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53560099/mapping-ordered-factors-to-colors-in-ggplot)), using `as_factor()` from `forcats`, but couldn't find the function. `as_factor()`  appears to be in `sjlabelled` (https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/sjlabelled/versions/1.1.3/topics/as_factor) but that also wouldn't work.

I tried making a simple reproducible example, but there the factors would map correctly. Essentially, I can't work out exactly how the factor is rendering the levels across continent and country.

I imagine there is a simple solution but I have been banging my head against the wall on this one.

In response to @Matt's comment below:

```
> dput(head(prod_cons_diff, n = 10))
structure(list(country = c("China", "USA", "India", "Japan", 
"Russian Federation", "Germany", "South Korea", "Saudi Arabia", 
"Iran", "Indonesia"), year = c(2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 
2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L), cons.e = c(2333.11521896672, 
1552.00682401808, 616.7239620176, 380.216883675894, 374.633869915012, 
244.223647570196, 182.62081469552, 169.164508003068, 166.402218417086, 
164.032430920609), iso3c = c("CHN", "USA", "IND", "JPN", "RUS", 
"DEU", "KOR", "SAU", "IRN", "IDN"), terr.e = c(2685.24946186172, 
1438.52306916917, 670.566180528622, 324.269234030281, 449.519945642447, 
217.785589557643, 174.832142238684, 172.780926461956, 187.211971723987, 
159.409240780077), diff.prod.cons.e = c(352.134242894999, -113.483754848911, 
53.8422185110221, -55.9476496456134, 74.8860757274351, -26.4380580125526, 
-7.78867245683526, 3.61641845888749, 20.8097533069009, -4.62319014053256
), prod.cons = c("Territorial > Consumption", "Consumption > Territorial", 
"Territorial > Consumption", "Consumption > Territorial", "Territorial > Consumption", 
"Consumption > Territorial", "Consumption > Territorial", "Territorial > Consumption", 
"Territorial > Consumption", "Consumption > Territorial"), continent = c("Asia", 
"Americas", "Asia", "Asia", "Europe", "Europe", "Asia", "Asia", 
"Asia", "Asia"), xstart = c(0.5, 1.5, 2.5, 3.5, 4.5, 5.5, 6.5, 
7.5, 8.5, 9.5), xend = c(1.5, 2.5, 3.5, 4.5, 5.5, 6.5, 7.5, 8.5, 
9.5, 10.5)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))
```

Comment: Can you please provide the output from `dput(head(prod_cons_diff, n = 10))`?

Comment: @Matt, thanks for looking at this. Added the requested output in the Q.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are defining `geom_rect` based on x values defined before the re-ordering of your dataset, your values won't match anymore the new ordering.

So, you need to re-calculate the position of `xstart` and `xend` for your `geom_rect` in order to match the new order of your dataset.

Here a possible solution for doing it using `dplyr` pipe sequence:

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>% arrange(diff.prod.cons.e) %>% 
  mutate(country = factor(country, unique(country)),
         continent = factor(continent, unique(continent))) %>%
  mutate(xstart2 = row_number() - 0.5, xend2 = row_number()+0.5)

              country year cons.e iso3c terr.e diff.prod.cons.e               prod.cons continent xstart xend xstart2 xend2
1                 USA 2017   1552   USA   1439          -113.00 Consumption>Territorial  Americas    1.5  2.5     0.5   1.5
2               Japan 2017    380   JPN    324           -55.90 Consumption>Territorial      Asia    3.5  4.5     1.5   2.5
3             Germany 2017    244   DEU    218           -26.40 Consumption>Territorial    Europe    5.5  6.5     2.5   3.5
4         South_Korea 2017    183   KOR    175            -7.79 Consumption>Territorial      Asia    6.5  7.5     3.5   4.5
5           Indonesia 2017    164   IDN    159            -4.62 Consumption>Territorial      Asia    9.5 10.5     4.5   5.5
6        Saudi_Arabia 2017    169   SAU    173             3.62 Territorial>Consumption      Asia    7.5  8.5     5.5   6.5
7                Iran 2017    166   IRN    187            20.80 Territorial>Consumption      Asia    8.5  9.5     6.5   7.5
8               India 2017    617   IND    671            53.80 Territorial>Consumption      Asia    2.5  3.5     7.5   8.5
9  Russian_Federation 2017    375   RUS    450            74.90 Territorial>Consumption    Europe    4.5  5.5     8.5   9.5
10              China 2017   2333   CHN   2685           352.00 Territorial>Consumption      Asia    0.5  1.5     9.5  10.5
```

So, now if you are passing these new positions into the `geom_rect` you can obtain the correct coloring patterns for continents:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

df %>% arrange(diff.prod.cons.e) %>% 
  mutate(country = factor(country, unique(country)),
         continent = factor(continent, unique(continent))) %>%
  mutate(xstart2 = row_number() - 0.5, xend2 = row_number()+0.5) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = country, y = diff.prod.cons.e * 3.664)) + 
  geom_point(aes(col = prod.cons)) + # add geom_point otherwise i can't map geom_rect (continuous) to country (discrete)
  geom_rect(aes(ymin = -1500, ymax = 1500, 
                xmin = xstart2, xmax = xend2, 
                fill = continent), alpha = 0.3, col = NA) + 
  geom_point(aes(col = prod.cons)) + # re-add geom_point so that it appears on top of the fill
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0, linetype = 'dashed') +
  coord_flip() +
  scale_color_manual(values = c('red', 'blue')) + 
  theme_minimal()
```

[image]

Comment: Great, thanks. This works. mutating to `factor()`, using `unique()`, is helpful. I hadn't thought of that.

Comment: You're welcome ;). Yes the combination or `arrange` and then use `unique` is pretty convenient for setting the appropriate order of a factor vector.