# Producing bar charts on ggplot2 using already summarized data

Tags: r, ggplot2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Create a bar graph with pre-summarized data using ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067452/create-a-bar-graph-with-pre-summarized-data-using-ggplot2)

On ggplot2 reference manual
http://had.co.nz/ggplot2/geom_bar.html

We can see that stacked bar charts are quite easy using the provided diamond data.

However, the dataset I am trying to use is different from the diamond data because mine is already summarized.

Attached is a minimal example of what I mean

```
   AgeGroup gender Level.of.Education  status count
1     18-25   male        High School married    10
2     18-25   male        High School  single    20
3     18-25   male            College married    25
4     18-25   male            College  single    10
5     18-25   male                PhD married    50
6     18-25   male                PhD  single     4
7     18-25   male                GED married    20
8     18-25   male                GED  single   100
9     18-25 female        High School married    20
10    18-25 female        High School  single    10
11    18-25 female            College married    30
12    18-25 female            College  single    60
13    18-25 female                PhD married    80
14    18-25 female                PhD  single    10
15    18-25 female                GED married     5
16    18-25 female                GED  single     2
```

Full dataset has timeframe as well so what I want to produce is a stacked bar graph showing number of married people and unmarried people overtime using "level of education" as fill on the bar.

Full dataset is so large that aggregate data like this is highly desired.

Your input would greatly help me. Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

you need `stat='identity'`.

```
ggplot(dat, aes(x=status, y=count, fill=Level.of.Education)) +
    geom_bar(stat='identity')
```

I'd also suggest faceting by gender:

```
ggplot(dat, aes(x=status, y=count, fill=Level.of.Education)) +
    geom_bar(stat='identity') +
    facet_wrap(~gender)
```